# How do I calculate a new column using tidy verse and summarise?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working on a dataset that requires me to split up the data by pitch type. Ideally, I am trying to find Swinging strike rate for each pitch type (swinging strike/total amount of pitches thrown).

The code I am using to split of pitchtypes is the following:

```
FFB16 <- Regseason2016 %>% 
  group_by(MLBID) %>% 
  filter(Pitch == "FF") %>% 
  summarise(avg16FFBeffectivesp = mean(effective_speed, na.rm = TRUE),
            avg16FFBspinrate = mean(release_spin_rate, na.rm = TRUE),
            avg16FFBpfx_x = mean(pfx_x, na.rm = TRUE),
            avg16FFBpfx_z = mean(pfx_z, na.rm = TRUE))
```

This spits out everything needed other then the swinging strike rate per pitch
But how would I calculate Swingstrike rate? I am aware of the mutate function but unsure of how to properly use it.

Ideally, I need something to calculate IF description = "swinging_strike" then count the total number for each ID then divide that by the total number of pitches thrown by each ID.

The description of the event (whether it was a swinging_strike or not) in my table is formatted like this:

```
**Description**
foul
swinging_strike
ball
called_strike
hit
swinging_strike
```

I am expecting my results to look like the following

```
MLBID  avgeffectivesp avgspinrate avgpfx_x  avgpfx_z  SwStr
1111    88.84         2500        -4.03      2.01      .45
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your summarize:

```
SwStr=sum(description=="swinging_strike", na.rm=TRUE)/n())
```